# VHDL Synthesizable Vector Compare

Tags: vector, vhdl

I am currently programming an ALU in VHDL and I am using a Cyclone II board. I need to compare two std_logic_vectors to see if one is greater than another. I used the greater than (>) in the condition but I don't know if the FPGA can synthesize that operator. Is there a workaround to compare two vectors without using ">" and synthesize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datatype `std_logic_vector` is just a set of bits (with 9 values ...), but it doesn't define any arithmetic behavior.

To use arithmetic operations like addition, multiplication or comparisons like your intended "greater than", you need another datatype for example `UNSIGNED` or `SIGNED`. These types define additional arithmetic operations. So when you declare your signals as (UN)SIGNED, VHDL will know the additional operators and a synthesizer will infer the correct hardware.

```
-- declare the signals in a declarative region
signal mySignal1 : UNSIGNED(7 downto 0);
signal mySignal2 : UNSIGNED(7 downto 0);
signal greater   : BOOLEAN;

-- now compare them
greater <= mySignal1 > mySignal2;
```

Answer (score 3):

An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful.  However, what you are trying to do is both possible in simulation and in synthesis.  What isn't clear from your question is what the format of the vectors are.  Are they signed?  Unsigned?  Two's complement?  Floating point?  Sign magnitude?

However, assume the two vectors are signed, 2's complement numbers.  One example:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity foo is

  port
  (
    a : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    b : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    y : out std_logic
  );
end entity foo;

architecture rtl of foo is
  signal a_signed : signed(a'range);
  signal b_signed : signed(b'range);
begin
  a_signed <= signed(a);
  b_signed <= signed(b);

  y <= '1' when (a_signed > b_signed) else '0';
end architecture rtl;
```

And there are other solutions as well.  And other implementations for different formats.